# What is 'layout-only view removal' optimization in react-native?

Tags: react-native

React native exposes certain props on `View` like [testID](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view#testid) that are super useful for native testing, but have following note attached to them

> This disables the 'layout-only view removal' optimization for this
>   view!

After searching for a while I was not able to find information that describes what this optimisation is. Is it significant? If it viable to only set these tests id's in dev mode / dev target? i.e. they will be undefined otherwise?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When RN creates the native views from the shadow nodes tree - it performs some optimizations. Views that do not actually show on screen (don't draw anything or just used in JSX to contain and layout their children) can be removed when constructing the native hierarchy. This is why they're called "layout-only" views.

As this warning suggests, a view with the `testID` prop will not be removed even if it's a "layout-only" view so it will actually be there when you're performing e2e tests.

Generally speaking, rendering a lot of views can cause performance issues, but using `testID` on some views won't make a noticeable difference in performance because:

1. You probably don't have a lot of views with a `testID`
2. Most of the views with a `testID` are probably not "layout-only" views so it makes no difference if you use this prop or not regarding the optimizations.

In case you do have "layout-only" views with a `testID`, it would be easier to move the `testID` to a more suitable view.

Comment: could you define what is a `layout-only` view to better understand the answer please ?

Comment: it's mentioned in the answer but i'll try to put it in other words: it's a view that's declared in JSX but doesn't actually show on screen and doesn't manipulate rendering of other views and thus can be flattened (essentially removed from the native view hierarchy) to improve performance

Comment: Thanks I understand better the concept now